# How to hide or spoof hardware info from the browser?

Tags: privacy, google-chrome, virtualization

I am using Google Chrome on a VirtualBox and Chrome detects my camera as '**VirtualBox WebCam**-USB 2.0 VGA'. How to prevent Chrome from reading device information or to make it read it as something else like 'USB 2.0'

I tried changing the *friendlyName* through Registry Editor Enum (New name is now visible through device manager) but Chrome still reads it as before.

Comment: Maybe use the “real” webcam using USB passthrough…?

Comment: @DanielB, you mean using this command "VBoxManage controlvm <VM name> webcam attach [host_path | alias ]"? I attached the "real" webcam using that only but chrome still detects it as "VirtualBox..."

Comment: 'USB 2.0 VGA' is my real webcam name(as seen from the device manager), but chrome on virtual box puts it as 'VirtualBox WebCam-USB 2.0 VGA' even tho the Virtualbox device manager also reads it as 'USB 2.0 VGA'.

Comment: No. I am referring to USB passthrough. It is unrelated to any webcam passthrough functionality VirtualBox may offer.

Comment: @DanielB, btw is there any alternative? even if it was not on a Virtualbox can you spoof device information on Google Chrome? thanks.

Comment: You might to use linux to perform tasks like this, unfortunately Microsoft in their infinite wisdom does not like user's modifying anything they want.